# Ransack search not returning expected results with enum field in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, ransack

I'm facing an issue with Ransack search in my Rails application when attempting to filter results based on an enum field. Despite implementing what appears to be a correct setup, the search doesn't return the expected results when i select any transaction type.  Here's a simplified version of my view and controller code related to the search functionality:

#Model code:

`enum transaction_type: %i[LedgerBook StaffLedgerBook Transfer ExpenseEntry Order PurchaseSaleDetail Salary SalaryDetail Investment Expense]`

#Views code:

```
<%= search_form_for @q, url: payments_path, class: "admin-controls" , method: "get" do |f| %>
  <div class="card col-lg-12 shadow mb-3 p-3">
    <div class="row mt-3">
      <div class="col-lg-3 form-group float-left">
        <%=f.select:account_id_in,options_from_collection_for_select(@accounts, "id" , ->(st){"#{st.title} \u{27F6}
          #{st.bank_name}"},f.object.account_id_in), {:include_blank => "Select the Account Title"},{:multiple =>
          true,:class=>"form-control chosen-select", :data => {:placeholder => "Select the Account Title"} } %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 form-group float-left">
        <%= f.search_field :id_eq, class: 'form-control input-sm ' , placeholder: "Enter Id" %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 form-group float-left">
        <%= f.select :transaction_type_eq, options_for_select(Payment.transaction_types.map { |key, value|
          [key.humanize, value] }, @transaction_type),{:include_blank=> "Select Type"}, { class: "form-control
          chosen-select", prompt: 'Select Type' }%>
      </div>
      <div class="ml-1">
        <p>From:</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 form-group float-left">
        <%= f.search_field :created_at_gteq,value: @start_date, class: 'form-control input-sm datepicker'
          , 'datepicker'=> true,placeholder: "YYYY-MM-DD" %>
      </div>
      <div class="ml-1">
        <p>To:</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 form-group float-left">
        <%= f.search_field :created_at_lteq,value: @end_date, class: 'form-control input-sm datepicker' , 'datepicker'=>
          true ,placeholder: "YYYY-MM-DD"%>
      </div>
      <div class="col-1 form-group float-left"> <button class="btn btn-primary" name="search_submit" type="submit"
          value="Search" style="width:100px;"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

# Controller code :

`if params[:q].present?   @title = params[:q][:account_title_cont]   @start_date = params[:q][:created_at_gteq]   @end_date = params[:q][:created_at_lteq]   @transaction_type = params[:q][:transaction_type_eq]   params[:q][:created_at_lteq] = params[:q][:created_at_lteq].to_date.end_of_day if params[:q][:created_at_lteq].present?   @q = Payment.where(max_credit: nil, max_debit: nil).ransack(params[:q]) else   @q = Payment.where(created_at: @start_date.to_date.beginning_of_day..@end_date.to_date.end_of_day, max_credit: nil, max_debit: nil).ransack(params[:q])`

`end`

In this code, I'm trying to filter payments based on an enum field transaction_type. However, the search results do not match the selected transaction type.  I have confirmed that the `@transaction_type` variable is correctly assigned, and the Ransack parameter names seem to align with the attributes in my model. The `options_for_select in` the view also looks correct.  Could someone please guide me on what might be causing this issue and how I can properly implement Ransack search with an enum field in Rails?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
ransacker :transaction_type, formatter: proc { |v| transaction_types[v] } do |parent|
    parent.table[:transaction_type]
  end
```